# How can I customize error messages from SmartGWT? (Not asking about i18n)

Tags: smartgwt

I am trying to get customized messages from SmartGWT (e.g. change "Must be a date" for another custom message). How can I get that String before it is shown to the user so I can edit it?

The question is for `FormItem` subclasses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
dynamicForm.setFieldErrors(fieldName, errorText, true);
```

[Here](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/DynamicForm.html#setFieldErrors%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) is the link for documentation.

Or the following is also similar:

```
dynamicForm.setErrors(map, true);
```

[Here](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/DynamicForm.html#setErrors%28java.util.Map,%20boolean%29) is the link for documentation.

Comment: It worked as I was expecting. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: RAS, after making some other tests, I noticed that, even though it show the customized error message by default, it does not change the message "Must be a date" when a invalid date is typed. Do you know any other way in order to accomplish this? Thanks in advance. You can see an  print screen here: http://oi58.tinypic.com/33tjgol.jpg

Comment: Have you applied any validator to dateitem? Can you show me your code for date validation?